# foldr lambda representation - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I understand this representation:

```
(foldr(\x acc -> x+10*acc) 0 n)
```

But recently i've come across with this one that i have not seen yet:

```
(foldr ((+) . aux . (\(a,b,c) -> c)) 0 list)
```

A brief explanation would be more than welcome!

Comment: `.` is the function composition operator. `(f . g) x == f (g x)`.

Comment: Why anyone would do this is beyond me. As well as being unreadable, it's also inefficient.

Comment: which one of the 2 is the inefficient one? I believe that the second one is a little bit more inefficient, but this was just as a curiosity. It makes sense now although :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(.)` is function composition operator, `(f . g) x = f (g x)`, so

```
    ((+) . aux . (\(a,b,c) -> c)) (a,b,c) d 
  = ((+) . aux) ((\(a,b,c) -> c) (a,b,c)) d 
  = ((+) . aux) c d
  = (+) (aux c) d 
  = aux c + d
```

This means that for `(foldr ((+) . aux . (\(a,b,c) -> c)) 0 list)` to be a well-typed expression, we must have types `list :: [(a,b,c)]` and `aux :: Num t => c -> t`; then the fold of a list  `[x1,x2,...,xn]` is equivalent to

```
aux3 x1 + (aux3 x2 + (... + (aux3 xn + 0) ...))
  where
     aux3 (a,b,c) = aux c
```